# Discord oAuth2 login after authorization was given

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord, symfony4

I have a symfony4 application and I'm using knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle to authenticate a user against discords oAuth endpoint.

The user clicks on the 'Login via Discord' button, he sees the authorization page from discord, accepts it and is now logged in on my page.
So far so good.

Here is what is not working:
The user is on another computer, so no session on my page. He logs in to discord web client. After that he visits my page but he is not logged in.
When he clicks again on 'Login via Discord' he sees the authorization page again instead of directly being logged in on my page.

Maybe I get something wrong here but usually when I use an oAuth login with google, facebook or anything else just like here on stackoverflow I never see the authorization page again. I click on 'login with XY' and, as long as I'm logged in to my corresponding account, I will immediately be logged in on the other page as well.

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\OAuth2Client;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Security\Authenticator\SocialAuthenticator;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

class DiscordAuthenticator extends SocialAuthenticator
{
    /**
     * @var \KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry
     */
    private $clientRegistry;

    /**
     * @var \App\Repository\UserRepository
     */
    private $repository;

    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * DiscordAuthenticator constructor.
     *
     * @param \KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry $clientRegistry
     * @param \App\Repository\UserRepository                 $repository
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface     $router
     */
    public function __construct(
        ClientRegistry $clientRegistry,
        UserRepository $repository,
        RouterInterface $router
    ) {
        $this->clientRegistry = $clientRegistry;
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse('/login/', Response::HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function supports(Request $request): bool
    {
        return $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'discord_set_token';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->fetchAccessToken($this->getDiscordClient());
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        try {
            /** @var \Wohali\OAuth2\Client\Provider\DiscordResourceOwner $discordUser */
            $discordUser = $this->getDiscordClient()
                                ->fetchUserFromToken($credentials);

            $email = $discordUser->getEmail();

            $existingUser = $this->repository->findOneBy(
                [
                    'externalId'       => $discordUser->getId(),
                    'externalIdSource' => 'discord',
                ]
            );

            if ($existingUser) {
                return $existingUser;
            }

            $user = $this->repository->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);

            if (!$user) {
                $user = new User(
                    $discordUser->getId(),
                    'discord',
                    $discordUser->getUsername(),
                    $discordUser->getEmail()
                );
                $user->setExternalId($discordUser->getId());
                $user->setExternalIdSource('discord');
                $user->setToken($credentials->getToken());
                $user->setRefreshToken($credentials->getRefreshToken());
                $user->setTokenExpiresFromTimestamp($credentials->getExpires());
            }

            $this->repository->persist($user);

            return $user;
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): Response
    {
        $message = strtr($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData());

        return new Response($message, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey): Response
    {
        $targetUrl = $this->router->generate('home');

        return new RedirectResponse($targetUrl);
    }

    /**
     * @return \KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\OAuth2Client
     */
    private function getDiscordClient(): OAuth2Client
    {
        return $this->clientRegistry
            ->getClient('discord');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \App\Repository\UserRepository
     */
    private $repository;

    /**
     * UserProvider constructor.
     *
     * @param \App\Repository\UserRepository $repository
     */
    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username): UserInterface
    {
        $user = $this->repository->findOneBy(['email' => $username]);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('No User with username %s found', $username));
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user): UserInterface
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
        }

        // TODO find out how to use the refresh token to get a new one

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function supportsClass($class): bool
    {
        return $class === User::class;
    }
}
```

```
security:
    providers:
        user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App:User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true

            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login

            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\DiscordAuthenticator

    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

/**
 * Class UserRepository
 */
class UserRepository
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
     */
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(User::class);
    }

    /**
     * Finds an entity by its primary key / identifier.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\User|null
     */
    public function find(int $id): ?User
    {
        return $this->repository->find($id);
    }

    /**
     * Finds all entities in the repository.
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\User[]
     */
    public function findAll(): iterable
    {
        return $this->repository->findAll();
    }

    /**
     * Finds entities by a set of criteria.
     *
     * @param array      $criteria
     * @param array|null $orderBy
     * @param int|null   $limit
     * @param int|null   $offset
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\User[]
     */
    public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null): iterable
    {
        return $this->repository->findBy($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset);
    }

    /**
     * Finds a single entity by a set of criteria.
     *
     * @param array      $criteria
     * @param array|null $orderBy
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\User|null
     */
    public function findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null): ?User
    {
        return $this->repository->findOneBy($criteria, $orderBy);
    }

    /**
     * Counts entities by a set of criteria.
     *
     * @param array $criteria
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function count(array $criteria): int
    {
        return $this->repository->count($criteria);
    }

    /**
     * Select all elements from a selectable that match the expression and
     * return a new collection containing these elements.
     *
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria $criteria
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\User[]
     */
    public function matching(Criteria $criteria): iterable
    {
        return $this->repository->matching($criteria);
    }

    /**
     * @param \App\Entity\User $user
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
     */
    public function persist(User $user): void
    {
        $this->entityManager->merge($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route(path="discord/")
 */
class DiscordOAuthController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var \KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry
     */
    private $clientRegistry;

    /**
     * DiscordOAuthController constructor.
     *
     * @param \KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry $clientRegistry
     */
    public function __construct(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry)
    {
        $this->clientRegistry = $clientRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * @Route(name="discord_redirect_authorization", path="redirect_authorization")
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function redirectAuthorizationAction(): Response
    {
        return $this->clientRegistry->getClient('discord')
                                    ->redirect(['identify', 'email', 'guilds']);
    }

    /**
     * @Route(name="discord_set_token", path="set_token")
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setTokenAction(): void
    {
        // empty as authenticator will handle the request
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a guard Authenticator? Its hard to know what's happening without seeing some code. Please add the relevant code to your question, thanks.

Comment: I have added the necessary code around security

Comment: Does your user repository actually have a persist method `$this->repository->persist($user)`? Can you post that?

Comment: I have added the user repository. I also checked the database my user is persisted.

Comment: why `merge()` and not `persist()`?

Comment: Is new user created with externalId?

Comment: With `merge()` the unit of work will find out itself if it should do an insert or an update which it does not with `persist()`. It is much easier. The saving of the user entity is not the issue saving and retrieving is working fine.
The issue is that the user always lands on the authorization page when he clicks on `Login with Discord` link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time I was working on this I didn't had much time and only briefly looked into the documentation.

Now I have had more time and put some time into reading the whole documentation of Discords oAuth.

I then found the query param `prompt` which when set to `none` will only once request the authorisation and otherwise will directly redirect to the `redirect_uri`